# objective-c releasing uninitialized class members in dealloc method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Regarding over-releasing. Say I have a instance variable defined in Test.h

```
NSString *mystring;
```

In my implementation Test.m I do not initialize the variable mystring anywhere. But I release it in dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [mystring release];
}
```

Is this now over-released? I've been doing the following in dealloc to avoid any issues, however, is this really necessary?

```
-(void)dealloc {
     if (mystring) [mystring release];
}
```

It seems that [nil release] shouldn't do anything, can someone verify this with class members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to over-release something that never existed in the first place.

Instance variables are initialized to nil and, thus, `[mystring release]` is messaging nil which is just fine in Objective-C.

Your -dealloc methods do need to call `[super dealloc]` at the end, though.

Comment: Ok great, sounds like I've been doing redundant checks.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you creating a variable at the class level that you're not initializing anywhere?

As this post is tagged iphone and it's IMPORTANT to manage your memory in the iphone environment it's always a good idea to release something if you've defined even if you don't assign it.

You can call release on an uninitialized variable without any problems, and be sure to `[super dealloc]`

Comment: For the sake of making the question simple. But, assume I have initialized mystring and released it somewhere else in the code, are there issues with calling release in dealloc without verifying it's not nil?

Comment: As bbum & myself said, you can release null to your hearts content.

Comment: You can release an uninitialised instance variable to your hearts content because it's not really an uninitialised variable - it's initialised to 0 by the runtime.  You cannot release an uninitialised variable if it's a local variable in a method or function.